# How to ignore/stop pusher from logging to console when running UI automated tests

Tags: logging, phantomjs, ui-automation, pusher, poltergeist

**Test setup:** Minitest+Capybara-poltergeist + phantomjs.

When I start running the test in headless mode, pusher logs messages to the console. Sometimes these messages are so many that I am missing the logs the test writes. I tried to ignore these messages by doing the following, but that did not help.

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, stdout: nil, phantomjs_logger: nil)
  end
```

**Example of pusher messages -**

Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected

Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting

Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws.pusherapp.com:443/{removed the text here}2?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.0.0&flash=false"}

Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected

Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"{removed the text here}","channel":"private-facility-{removed the text here}}}

Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"private-facility-{removed the text here}}

Pusher : No callbacks on private-{removed the text here} for pusher:subscription_succeeded

Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting

Any inputs on how to stop logging to console?

Answer (score 0):

The Pusher JavaScript library only logs to the console if the `Pusher.log` property has been assigned a function to do so:

```
Pusher.log = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};
```

To ensure that logging doesn't take place within your test you should make sure no code has been written to the something similar to the example above. To make sure you could simply `null` the `Pusher.log` property prior to running your tests.

For more information see the docs on [Pusher JavaScript logging](https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging).

Comment: When I set pusher.log to null, I get an error message -'Minitest::UnexpectedError: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+). Does this mean, pusher.log value should be changed in the application code?

Comment: `Pusher.log` is a static property on the `Pusher` definition (see the uppercase `P`). It's not an instance property.

Comment: I typed it here as pusher.log, but I actually set Pusher.log in my tests.

Comment: It would seem unlikely that the error you're seeing is triggered by a JavaScript error. To clarify `Pusher.log` should be set in the JavaScript context and not in the Ruby test context.

Answer (score 0):

add these     Pusher.logToConsole = false; ex: "useEffect(() => {
Pusher.logToConsole = false;

```
const pusher = new Pusher(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_PUSHERSOCKETS_ID, {
  cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_PUSHER_CLUSTER,
});

const channel = pusher.subscribe("sample-channel");
channel.bind("sample-event", function (data) {
  setEvent({ ...event, data: data, status: true });
});

if (event.status) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setEvent({ ...event, status: false });
  }, 1000);
}
// Cleanup function to unsubscribe when the component unmounts
return () => {
  channel.unbind_all();
  channel.unsubscribe();
};
```

}, []);"